# Heroku node.js remote DoS Constant Hashtable Seeds vulnerability

Tags: node.js, security, heroku, ddos

I just got an email from Heroku about the node.js remote Denial of Service (DoS) Constant Hashtable Seeds vulnerability:

```
The Node.js team has announced that a high severity remote Denial of Service (DoS) Constant Hashtable Seeds vulnerability in Node.js versions 4.x through 8.x has been patched in the following versions:

4.8.4
6.11.1
7.10.1
8.1.4

Detecting if you're vulnerable from the Heroku CLI
$ heroku run node -v -a APPNAME

If your version is less than what's listed above, you will need to upgrade.
```

When I run the above command, I get:

```
v0.10.48
```

Do I need to do anything? If so, what?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The comment in the [official document](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/july-2017-security-releases/) says:

> Note: The 0.10.x and 0.12.x release lines are also vulnerable to the Constant Hashtable Seeds vulnerability. We recommend that users of these release lines upgrade to one of the supported LTS release lines.

So yes, you are still affected. You need to upgrade to a later ( and just recently released ) version, one of:

- Node.js 8.1.4
- Node.js 7.10.1
- Node.js 6.11.1
- Node.js 4.8.4

Answer (score -1):

You're running a version that's almost a year old. I don't know if it's vulnerable to the issue you're talking about but I'm sure it would not hurt to upgrade!